# Jquery.Validate

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms, jquery-validate

Fala pessoal, tudo certo!?

Estou quebrando a cabeça com o seguinte, estou utilizando o plugin do jquery validate, funcionando tudo certo, mas no meu formulário estou utilizando um botão que não quero que valide no submit, mas mesmo colocando a propriedade formnovalidate o formulario continua validando o que será que estou fazendo errado, abaixo o trecho do meu código.
  Estou utilizando asp.net webforms com jquery...

código na pagina:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPesquisarSerie" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm" runat="server"  Text="Buscar" OnClientClick="return ValidaPesquisarSerie();" OnClick="btnPesquisarSerie_Click" formNoValidate />
```

código gerado no html

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$MainContainer$btnPesquisarSerie" value="Buscar" onclick="return ValidaPesquisarSerie();" id="ctl00_MainContainer_btnPesquisarSerie" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" formNoValidate="" />
```

meu código do validate:

```
$('#aspnetForm').validate({
                debug: true,
                invalidHandler:  function(event, validator) {
                    //$(".tab-content").find("div.tab-pane:hidden:has(div.has-error)")
                    //mostra a tab com erro
                    $(".tab-content").find("div.tab-pane:hidden:has(label.state-error)").each(function (index, tab) {
                        var id = $(tab).attr("id");
                        $('a[href="#' + id + '"]').tab('show');
                    });
                },
                ignore: "", //validar os campos com hidden... necessário pelo tab utilizado.
                rules: {
                    <%=txtNomeLiberador.UniqueID%>: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    <%=txtDataLiberacaoTecnica.UniqueID%>: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    <%=txtTemperaturaInterna.UniqueID%>: {
                        required: true,
                        range: [-30, 30]
                    },
                    <%=txtTemperaturaExterna.UniqueID%>: {
                        required: true,
                        range: [0, 50]
                    },
                    <%=txtPressaoSuccao.UniqueID%>: {
                        required: true,
                        range: [10, 60]
                    },
                    <%=txtPressaoDescarga.UniqueID%>: {
                        required: true,
                        range: [250, 425]
                    },
                    <%=txtTensaoSaidaAlternador.UniqueID%>: {
                        required: true,
                        range: [12, 30]
                    },
                    <%=txtConsumoCorrenteEletrica.UniqueID%>: {
                        required: true,
                        range: [0, 60]
                    },
                    <%=txtHorasFuncionamento.UniqueID%>: {
                        required: true,
                        range: [0, 10]
                    },
                    <%=chkListaCheckList.UniqueID%>: {
                        required: true,
                        minlegth: 17
                    },
                    <%=txtNroSerie.UniqueID%>: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    <%=txtModelo.UniqueID%>: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    <%=txtCustoInstalacao.UniqueID%>: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    <%=txtCPF_CNPJ.UniqueID%>: {
                        required: true
                    },
                    <%=txtNomeCliente.UniqueID%>: {
                        required: true
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    <%=txtNomeLiberador.UniqueID%>: {
                        required: "Informe o nome do liberador"
                    },
                    <%=txtDataLiberacaoTecnica.UniqueID%>: {
                        required: "Informe a data da instalação do aparelho"
                    },
                    <%=txtTemperaturaInterna.UniqueID%>: {
                        required: "Informe a Temperatura Interna",
                        range: "a temperatura interna deve estar entre {0} e {1} graus"
                    },
                    <%=txtTemperaturaExterna.UniqueID%>: {
                        required: "Informe a Temperatura Externa",
                        range: "a temperatura externa deve estar entre {0} e {1} graus"
                    },
                    <%=txtPressaoSuccao.UniqueID%>: {
                        required: "Informe a pressão de sucção",
                        range: "a pressão de sucção deve estar entre {0} e {1} psi"
                    },
                    <%=txtPressaoDescarga.UniqueID%>: {
                        required: "Informe a pressão de descarga",
                        range: "a pressão de descarga deve estar entre {0} e {1} psi"
                    },
                    <%=txtTensaoSaidaAlternador.UniqueID%>: {
                        required: "Informe a tensão de saida do alternador",
                        range: "a pressão de saida do alternador deve estar entre {0} e {1} V"
                    },
                    <%=txtConsumoCorrenteEletrica.UniqueID%>: {
                        required: "Informe o consumo da corrente eletrica",
                        range: "o consumo da corrente elétrica deve estar entre {0} e {1} A"
                    },
                    <%=txtHorasFuncionamento.UniqueID%>: {
                        required: "Informe quantas horas de funcionamento da maquina foram realizadas para o teste",
                        range: "as horas de funcionamento devem estar entre {0} e {1}"
                    },
                    <%=chkListaCheckList.UniqueID%>: {
                        required: "Verifique o checklist, existe algum não marcado!"
                    },
                    <%=txtNroSerie.UniqueID%>: {
                        required: "Informe a serie do aparelho"
                    },
                    <%=txtModelo.UniqueID%>: {
                        required: "Informe o modelo do aparelho"
                    },
                    <%=txtCustoInstalacao.UniqueID%>: {
                        required: "Informe o custo de instalação"
                    },
                    <%=txtCPF_CNPJ.UniqueID%>: {
                        required: "Informe o CNPJ/CPF do cliente"
                    },
                    <%=txtNomeCliente.UniqueID%>: {
                        required: "Nome do cliente é obrigatório"
                    }
                }
            });
```

Qualquer ajuda é bem vinda...
Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Na inicialização, defina um seletor para os campos ignorados. Por exemplo, para que o plugin ignore todos os elementos que tenham `class="ignore"` faça assim:

```
$('#aspnetForm').validate({
    ...
    ignore: ".ignore",
    ...
});
```

Comment: Não quero que ele ignore os campos quero ele não faça o validate quando clicar em um determinado botão... a minha classe ignore acima esta vazia porque utilizo um tab e quero que ele valide os campos hidden...a principio a tag formnovalidate deveria funcionar...

Comment: Hmm, entendi. De fato, de acordo com [a documentação](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference#link-skipping-validation-on-submit) deveria funcionar. Já tentou especificar o atributo em caixa-baixa? `formnovalidate` ao invés de `formNoValidate`